# Can't solve table issue

Tags: r

I have some problems when using R

```
head(data)
  pclass.survived.sex.age
1           1,1,female,29
2           1,1,male,0.92
3            1,0,female,2
4             1,0,male,30
5           1,0,female,25
6             1,1,male,48

table(data$survived,data$sex)
# < table of extent 0 x 0 >
```

what does this mean table of extent 0x0 and how can I solve this?
Column `sex` is female and male.
Column `survived` is 1 and 0

Comment: You read your data in wrong. It looks like a csv, but everything is in one variable now. That's why the column 'sex' doesn't exist.

Comment: Please show how you imported your `data` into R.

Comment: It doesn't look that urgent.

Comment: Try reading your data using `read.csv` or using `data.table::fread`

Comment: You could also check your actual column names and length using `ncol(data)` and `colnames(data)`

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you  have imported your file incorrectly. Usually, you would read your `.csv` file in a manner similar to the code below:

```
df <- read.csv("myRandomFile.csv", header=TRUE)
```

When reading data from Excel you could make use of a designated package, like in the example below:

```
library(XLConnect) # load XLConnect package 
wk = loadWorkbook("mydata.xls") 
df = readWorksheet(wk, sheet="Sheet1")
```

After, it would be good to check the import with use of `dim`, `rownames` and `colnames`. If you are experiencing problems with reading your file correctly you may consider [reading it line by line](http://www.r-bloggers.com/read-line-by-line-of-a-file-in-r/) for a few initial lines and posting a reproducible example here so other users can suggest solutions.